# Weird FireFox Flash behaviour

Tags: xml, flash, firefox

I am getting this really weird behaviour on my firefox browser.

I have a flash component written in flex which reads a xml file and shows up its data. This works fine in IE and Chrome, but not in Firefox.

When i used fiddler to check for the problem, it started working fine.
And now i have come to the conclusion that when fillder is running in the background and i access the flash component it works fine (reads all the xml data and shows it up), but when i close fiddler and do the same....i get the following error, "Error reading {myfilename} file."

Can someone make me understand how fiddler is helping firefox read the xml file....

many thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks folks for the help but later i found that there was a bug in the code written in flex.
once i corrected that everything worked like hot knife through butter...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried opening the XML file directly in Firefox? I'm guessing there's an error in your XML file that is causing Firefox to "choke". Fiddler filters all HTTP requests through its proxy before they get to your app so that could be causing this anomaly.

Is your XML encoded correctly with something like this at the top?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Try running your XML file through a validator such as http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp
to catch any errors.